# How to change remote file permission via FTPClient

Tags: ftp, file-permissions, chmod, apache-commons-net

I need to handle remote file on a ftp server via **commons-net-1.4.1.jar**,class **org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient**.It's seems that no api available to change a file's permission,just like unix shell command chmod.

Anyone know any solution to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTP doesn't have a command for such operations, since the operation is platform-specific. If your library supports this, you can try using SITE command and pass the command line as a parameter of SITE command. Some servers support this trick to run shell commands.

Comment: Thanks,Eugene.I sent a chmod command to remote ftp server successfully via org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.sendSiteCommand(String arguments)